# Joomla and Jomsocial 2.6- I need Spanish and English version in single site

Tags: php, joomla, multilingual, jomsocial

Hope you are doing great friends.

I have installed Joomla in my site and now I installed Jomsocial, a social plug-in; the thing is that I installed it in English but now I want to install it in Spanish but keep it in both languages, I mean let's said I will have a link to the Spanish version and other for the English version but obviously I need to share the database to keep all users connected (all signups in English and Spanish together), is it possible? Any ideas on how to do that? I have the Spanish version already but not sure if I have to follow the normal installation through the extension manager and then make some code changes.

I’ll really appreciate your help guys, I know some php if some code changes are needed , I mean,  if you advise me to change something.

Have a great evening!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jom social has a built in language pack in Spanish which you must install (can be found [here](http://www.jomsocial.com/customize/addons/languages)). Also install the main Joomla Language pack (from [here](http://community.joomla.org/translations/joomla-16-translations.html)).

You can then handle the site natively in Joomla using the multilingual plugin (you will need to enable this).

Else install a component such as JoomFish (I believe the 2.5 version is only a paid membership thing for now - but a free one will probably come soon) or FaLang (free but I personally don't find as good). There are also other components available on [JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/) which will manage the translations better than the native Joomla plugin. However the above two langauge files will need to be installed either way!

Comment: Thanks a lot George for taking the time to answer my question, I'll take a look to your suggestions and will reopen the question in a more concise way if I need more assistance. Your help has been really appreciated pal!